# Can php for loop used within mysql query to insert data?

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

```
$insert_additional_info=sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_additional_info (productid,size_d,size_d1,bags,cartons,retail_price,sales_price,wholesale_price) VALUES (%s, %s,%s, %s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($product_id, "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($size_d, "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($size_d1, "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($bags, "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($cartons, "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($retail_price, "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($sales_price, "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($wholesale_price, "int"));
```

Instead of INSERTING like above, is there a way that I can use loop inside the VALUES()?

The reason is , my output or value to be inserted generated by looping like this.

```
if( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{

$_SESSION['myInputs_all'] = array($_POST["myInputs_d"],$_POST["myInputs_d1"],$_POST["myInputs_bags"],$_POST["myInputs_carton"],$_POST["myInputs_retail"],$_POST["myInputs_sales"],$_POST["myInputs_wholesale"]);

$counter = count( $_POST['myInputs_d']);
$column_array=array('productid,size_d,size_d1,bags,cartons');
 for( $c = 0; $c < $counter; $c++ )
  {
       foreach( $myInputs_all as $all_inputs=>$value )
       {
           //This is the output
           echo $value[$c];
        }
 }
}
```

Now, how do I insert echo $value[$c]; inside the VALUES for the INSERT QUERY?

I tried something like below but it says Query is empty. But this is how I want to solve it.

```
$insert_additional_info="INSERT INTO tbl_additional_info (productid,size_d,size_d1,bags,cartons) VALUES(";
   $counter = count( $_POST['myInputs_d']);

   for( $c = 0; $c < $counter; $c++ )
  {
       foreach( $myInputs_all as $all_inputs=>$value )
       {
   $insert_additional_info.=$value[$c];  
   $insert_additional_info.=")"; 
        }  
 }
```

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123, I did that but instead of just looping columns it, loops through rows as well

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123, I'm not very sure how you meant to use explode. Have a look at the edited part,that's what I want to achieve.Thanks

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123, okay ..no problem..

Answer (score 0):

By using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), you can prepare the Query with variables for the values you want to insert. Now you can loop trough an array with the values you want to insert, an map them with PDO::bindParam and execute the query inside the Loop.

E.g.:

```
$stmt=$handler->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_additional_info
(productid,size_d,size_d1,bags,cartons,retail_price,sales_price,wholesale_price)
VALUES (var1, var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8");
foreach($Array as $data){
$stmt->bindParam(":var1",$dara["value1"]);
$stmt->bindParam(":var2",$dara["value2"]);
$stmt->bindParam(":var3",$dara["value3"]);
....
$stmt->bindParam(":var8",$dara["value8"]);
$stmt->execute();
}
```